# Variety of maximal isotropic subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-geometry, quadrics

Suppose that $V$ is a complex vector space of even dimension $2n$. Let $Q:V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ a bilinear, non degenerate, symmetric bilinear form over the field of complex numbers.
Set $$\Sigma=\{ \Lambda \subset C: Q(\Lambda, \Lambda)\equiv 0   \} \subset G(n,2n),$$  the set af all maximal isotropic subspaces of $V$ where $G(n,2n)$ is the grasmannian.
How can I prove that the set $\Sigma$ as a subset of $G(n,2n)$ is a smooth variety and of which dimension?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** By construction, the standard action of the special orthogonal Lie group $SO(Q)$ on $V$ induces a transitive action on $\Sigma$.

Comment: Do you know a standard book where i can find information on group action acting on a set or in particular an algebraic variety?

Comment: I suggest you ask this s a separate question to get recommendations. If you do this, it would be useful for you to (1) specify your interests clearly and specifically, and (2) apply tag the question with the $\texttt{reference-request}$ tag.

Comment: i've asked the question separately.